# Error 404 en petición tipo PUT con Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema con una petición tipo `PUT` a través de ajax, ya que obtengo por respuesta `ERROR 404`.

Lo que deseo hacer, es realizar la actualización del campo 'estado' en la tabla compra, mediante ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#cerrar').click(function(){
var registro=$('#cerrar').val();  
var route="http://127.0.0.1:8000/almacen/compras/"+registro;
var token=$("input[name=_token]").val();
$.ajax({  
   url:route,
   headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
   type:'PUT',
   dataType:'json',
   data:{ 
    estado:2
   },
   success:function(){
    alert('correcto');
  }

});
```

Donde recibiría dicha petición con la funcion 'cerrar' en el controller de la siguiente forma:

```
public function cerrar(Request $request, $id){
    $compra=compra::find($id);
    $compra->fill($request->input('estado'));
    $compra->save();
       return response()->json([
             "mensaje"=>"Actualizacion de registro correcto." 
        ]);
}
```

Ruta:

```
Route::PUT('/almacen/compras','COmpraController@cerrar');
```

Pero al ejecutarla la respuesta es lo siguiente:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Comment: ¿cómo está definida la ruta?

Comment: Route::PUT('/almacen/compras','COmpraController@cerrar');

Comment: Así esta definida la ruta Shaz

Comment: La ruta estaba mal definida, pues me falto el parámetro que envió, ahora ya  lo corregi y quedo asi Route::PUT('/almacen/compras/{id}','COmpraController@cerrar');, pero me responde con el error 500

Comment: Revisa el log de Lavel, ahí está la respuesta.

Comment: Deberias definir la ruta esperando un parametro en este caso el registro segun el codigo, algo como `Route::PUT('/almacen/compras/{id}','COmpraController@cerrar');` es decir añadiendo`/{id}`

Comment: Ya lo corregi, pero ahora tengo el error 500

Comment: Revisa el log como indico Shaz, edita la pregunta y muestranos que error concreto te esta dando

Comment: Que tal si usas axios en vez de jquery?